# R minus sign missing when convert character to numeric by as.numeric

Tags: r, char, spatial, numeric

I have large spatial data set in text. i need to convert degree minute.decimal values to decimal degrees. my code as follows. it works well values except 0 to -1. values in 0 to -1 convert to positive values by as.numeric()
Coordinate conversion method is fine, but problem is how to pass minus zero (-0) values in iflese statement. 
how i overcome this problem?

```
data <- c("-7ø12.2","-1ø23.0","-0ø50.3","0ø14.6","2ø59.7")
# latitudes in degree minutes.decimal format
lat1 <- as.numeric(gsub( "ø.*$", "", data)) # substring befor ø
lat2 <- as.numeric(sub(".*ø", "", data)) # substring after ø
lat <-  ifelse(lat1 < 0, lat1 - lat2 / 60, lat1 +  lat2 / 60)
```

> lat1
>   [1] -7 -1  0  0  2

Comment: This is a potential duplicate to [Converting geo coordinates from degree to decimal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14404596/converting-geo-coordinates-from-degree-to-decimal)

Comment: @UweBlock  Here question is not the conversion from degree to decimal, but avoid minus zero values (0 to -1) to being positive in ifelse statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are testing for `lat1 < 0` but `lat1[3]` is `0` so the test fails, and your `ifelse` hits the addition result. You appear to be hoping that `-0` stays negative but that's not how `0` works.

Add another extraction (the negative sign):

```
neg <- substr(data, 1, 1)
neg
#> [1] "-" "-" "-" "0" "2"
```

and test on that instead of `lat1 < 0`

```
ifelse(neg == "-", lat1 - lat2 / 60, lat1 +  lat2 / 60) 
#> [1] -7.2033333 -1.3833333 -0.8383333  0.2433333  2.9950000
```

Comment: @ Jonathan very helpful answer.