# Error when converting latitude and longitude from degrees, minutes and seconds to decimal degrees using measurements package

Tags: r, units-of-measurement

**Short version:** I have a dataframe with two columns: Latitude and Longitude, being each of them in degrees, minutes and seconds. After reading some similar questions [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14404596/converting-geo-coordinates-from-degree-to-decimal), I decided to use `measurements` package to make the conversion, but results get messed when converting from one unit to another (see below).

**Detailed version:**

Provided the following dataframe where I have two columns, `Latitude` and `Longitude` expressed in degrees, minutes and seconds

```
df = data.frame(
      Latitude = c("15° 33' 9\"",NA,"52° 58' 13\"", NA, "21° 1' 28\"", "21° 2' 26\"", "10° 47' 31\"", NA, "-34° 53' 38\"", "41° 7' 56\""), 
      Longitude = c("48° 30' 59\"", NA, "-3° 10' 13\"", NA, "105° 50' 34\"", "105° 47' 52\"", "106° 41' 29\"", NA, "-56° 8' 16\"", "-104° 46' 30\""))
```

I want to convert those values into decimal degrees by using `measurements` package as follows:

```
library(measurements)

# Turn degrees, minutes and seconds into spaces so they can be used with
# measurements::conv_unit.
df$Latitude = str_replace(df$Latitude, "°", "")
df$Latitude = str_replace(df$Latitude, "'", "")
df$Latitude = str_replace(df$Latitude, "\"", "")

df$Longitude = str_replace(df$Longitude, "°", "")
df$Longitude = str_replace(df$Longitude, "'", "")
df$Longitude = str_replace(df$Longitude, "\"", "")


# Use measurements::conv_unit to convert to decimal degrees.
df$Latitude = conv_unit(df$Latitude, "deg_min_sec", "dec_deg")
df$Longitude = conv_unit(df$Longitude, "deg_min_sec", "dec_deg")
```

However, I get the following output:

```
> df
       Latitude     Longitude     Latitude_dec    Longitude_dec
1    15° 33' 9"   48° 30' 59"          15.5525 48.5163888888889
2          <NA>          <NA>             <NA>             <NA>
3   52° 58' 13"   -3° 10' 13"             <NA>             <NA>
4          <NA>          <NA>           1.4725 50.5958333333333
5    21° 1' 28"  105° 50' 34" 2.43611111111111 47.8961111111111
6    21° 2' 26"  105° 47' 52"             <NA>             <NA>
7   10° 47' 31"  106° 41' 29" 34.8938888888889 56.1377777777778
8          <NA>          <NA> 41.1322222222222          104.775
9  -34° 53' 38"   -56° 8' 16"               -0               -0
10   41° 7' 56" -104° 46' 30"                0               -0
```

As you can see, first row calculated fields seem to be right, whereas starting with line 3, results get messed up, and, hence, being completely useless.

I have read `?conv_unit` several times and I don't find any mistake. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`conv_unit` apparently breaks when NA present, presumably because of the way it parses using `unlist(strsplit(...` as in this line of the source code

```
secs = lapply(split(as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(x, 
                " "))) * c(3600, 60, 1), f = rep(1:length(x), 
                each = 3)), sum)
```

So I think you need to ignore `NA` when you convert, like this:

```
library(measurements)

df = data.frame(
   Latitude = c("15° 33' 9\"",NA,"52° 58' 13\"", NA, "21° 1' 28\"", "21° 2' 26\"", "10° 47' 31\"", NA, "-34° 53' 38\"", "41° 7' 56\""), 
   Longitude = c("48° 30' 59\"", NA, "-3° 10' 13\"", NA, "105° 50' 34\"", "105° 47' 52\"", "106° 41' 29\"", NA, "-56° 8' 16\"", "-104° 46' 30\""))

# Turn degrees, minutes and seconds into spaces so they can be used with
# measurements::conv_unit.
# NOTE THIS CAN BE DONE IN ONE OR TWO LINES USING REGEX "OR" (|)
#  - I would think this could be done in stringr::str_replace too
#  - but I don't know how.
df$Latitude = gsub("°|'|\"", "", df$Latitude)
df$Longitude = gsub("°|'|\"", "", df$Longitude)

# Use measurements::conv_unit to convert to decimal degrees.
not_na <- !is.na(df$Latitude) #identify non-na (I assume same for Long here)
#convert only non-na values
df$Latitude[not_na] = conv_unit(df$Latitude[not_na], "deg_min_sec", "dec_deg")
df$Longitude[not_na] = conv_unit(df$Longitude[not_na], "deg_min_sec", "dec_deg")
```

which gives

> ```
> df
>             Latitude         Longitude
> 1            15.5525  48.5163888888889
> 2               <NA>              <NA>
> 3   52.9702777777778 -3.17027777777778
> 4               <NA>              <NA>
> 5   21.0244444444444  105.842777777778
> 6   21.0405555555556  105.797777777778
> 7   10.7919444444444  106.691388888889
> 8               <NA>              <NA>
> 9  -34.8938888888889 -56.1377777777778
> 10  41.1322222222222          -104.775
> ```

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution (and improvements on my code). I guessed it had something to do with NA, but didn't know how to get any clue nor how to face it. Very smart solution!