# measurements::conv_unit() returns character vector where numeric expected

Tags: r

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14404596/converting-geo-coordinates-from-degree-to-decimal) and related, I am using measurements::conv_unit() to convert Degree:Min:Sec coordinates to decimal.
However, whilst of correct 'value', my return is a character vector, not numeric as should be according to all I've seen elsewhere. 
My input is character as per per `?measurements::conv_unit : "Coordinate: Values must be entered as a string with one space between subunits (e.g. 70° 33’ 11” = "70 33 11")."`

Example:

```
df <- c("1 1 1", "-1 1 1", "2 2 2","-2 2 2")  

measurements::conv_unit(df, from = 'deg_min_sec', to = 'dec_deg')
[1] "1.01694444444444"  "-1.01694444444444" "2.03388888888889"  "-2.03388888888889"
```

The conversion to numeric (via as.numeric()) is of course a simple solution, but this shouldn't be needed in the first place I believe.
The result is same whether I define df as c(), data.frame() or tibble(), and even when above is run in a clean (restarted) R session.
Measurements version 1.1.0, installed just today.

Am I doing something wrong or what's happening?

Comment: This is intended as per the source code: `if (to == "dec_deg") 
            inter = as.character(lapply(secs, function(y) y/3600))`

Comment: Thank you @LyzandeR. Good to know it's meant to be, even though not intuitive.

Comment: @LyzandeR. If you set your comment as answer i can accept ;-)

Comment: Sure, @Robbes. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is intended as per the source code of `conv_unit`:

```
if (to == "dec_deg") inter = as.character(lapply(secs, function(y) y/3600))
```